# epoll server with EPOLLET. When should I mark a socket with EPOLLOUT?

Tags: c, sockets, server, nonblocking, epoll

So been trying to make an asynchronous server with epoll (edge-triggered). Everything seems to work fine unless I send large files (30-33 MB) over the socket, which ofcourse gives EAGAIN with send since it fills up the kernel buffer. For now, I just keep sending it in the loop, not doing anything if I get EAGAIN, wasting CPU time.

So, to bring EPOLLOUT into the picture, and from reading a lot of articles, what I should do is set the EPOLLOUT flag on the socket when send returns -1 with EAGAIN, break out of the while loop, go to the main event loop, wait until `events[i]->events & EPOLLOUT`becomes true, send the left over message again, and if all the bytes are done, remove the EPOLLOUT flag from the socket.

Is my approach correct? Or is there a better way to do this? I ask because I currently keep a global `send_buff` which is being re-used for all the clients to whom I send a response. If I implement the above approach, I'd need to have one buffer per client, because I need to keep the "unsend" message which I couldn't due to send() returning -1. Isn't that memory inefficient? If I have 1000 clients, each of which are asking for 1 MB worth of data, then it means I would have to allocate buffers which amount to 1 GB in total! Moreover, I would need to implement a queue structure, which tracks the sockets which have pending sends and then either using FIFO or some priority, send them out when send becomes ready to send again.

Is this how production servers are designed? What strategies do they use in their code?

Next, the second thing I wanted to ask is that when I see the packets that are being sent using wireshark, I always get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/css)Continuation`. This continuation is something new which didn't happen when I plain non-blocking sockets. What could have caused this?

Here's the code for reference. Any help and tips to better the code is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Here's the server_t struct, which has one buffer (the global buffer) ->

```
#define RECV_SIZE 2048
typedef struct server_ds {
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in info;
  char *reply;
} server_t;

server_t server;
```

Here's the event loop ->

```
 for (;;) {
    // printf("before wait\n");
    nfds = epoll_wait(event->epollfd, event->events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
    // printf("after wait\n");

    if (nfds == -1) {
      perror("epoll_wait()");
      return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
      if (event->events[i].events == EPOLLHUP) {
        fprintf(stderr, "got EPOLLUP\n");
      }
      if (event->events[i].events == EPOLLERR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "got EPOLLERR\n");
      }
      if (event->events[i].data.fd == server.sockfd &&
          event->events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
        // we recieved a new connection on the socket that the server is
        // listening on accept all the incoming new connections
        while (1) {
          memset(&in_addr, 0, sizeof(in_addr));
          in_len = sizeof(in_addr);

          int connfd =
              accept(server.sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&in_addr, &in_len);

          if (connfd == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
              // we have accepted all the connections that we could
              // no more connection, break out of this loop
              break;
            }
            perror("accept()");
            break;
          }

          printf("New client %d connection!\n", connfd);
          if (make_socket_nonblocking(connfd) == -1) {
            continue;
          }

          event->ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLOUT ;
          event->ev.data.fd = connfd;

          if (epoll_ctl(event->epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connfd, &event->ev) <
              0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "epoll set insertion error: fd=%d", connfd);
            close(connfd);
            continue;
          }
        }

      // }else if (event->events[i].events & EPOLLOUT ){
      //     printf("recieved : EPOLLOUT \n");
      //     event->events[i].events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
      //     if( epoll_ctl(event->epollfd,EPOLL_CTL_MOD,event->events[i].data.fd,&event->events[i]) < 0 ){
      //       perror("epoll_ctl()");
            
      //     }
      }else if (event->events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
        // client has send some data to the socket
        // recieve all the data at once
        int client_fd = event->events[i].data.fd;
        char buffer[RECV_SIZE];
        int client_closed = 0;

        while (1) {
          char *ptr = buffer;
          ssize_t bytes = recv(client_fd, ptr, RECV_SIZE - 1, 0);
          if (bytes == 0) {
            // client has closed the connection
            // close the client socket and remove from the epoll_loop_t
            printf("Client %d closed connection\n", client_fd);
            client_closed = 1;
            close(client_fd);
            break;
          } else if (bytes == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
              // we have read all we could
              // break from the while loop
              break;
            }
            perror("recv()");
            break;
          } else {
            ptr[bytes] = '\0';
            ptr += bytes;
          }
        }
        // if client has not closed the socket
        // only then send the reply
        //printf("client closed var : %d\n", client_closed);
        if (!client_closed) {
          http_t request;
          // parse_request returns -1 when the request is something other than
          // GET request. In that case we send the default NOT implemented
          // message to the client
          if (parse_request(buffer, strlen(buffer), &request) == -1) {
            // send_all returns -1 only when send() call returns with EAGAIN or
            // EWOULDBLOCK this indicates that the send buffers are full retry
            // it again later
            if (send_all(client_fd, strlen(not_implemented_reply),
                         not_implemented_reply) == -1) {
              // for now continue
              // to be implemented later
              continue;
            }
          }

          printf("sending response...\n");
          send_response(&request, client_fd);
          printf("sent OK reply\n");

          // free the server reply which was created using malloc
          if (server.reply != NULL) {
            free(server.reply);
            server.reply = NULL;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the send_all() function ( send_response() calls send_all() internally after some preprocessing of the data )

```
int send_all(int sockfd, size_t len, const char *reply) {
  ssize_t bytes = 0;
  int send_size = 4028;
  size_t total_sent = 0;
  // printf("file size: %ld\n", len);
  while (len) {
    bytes = send(sockfd, reply, len, 0);
    printf("b sent : %ld\n",bytes);
    if (bytes == -1) {
      if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
        // the send() buffer is full, retry it later
        // printf("got EAGAIN\n");
        continue;
      }
    }
    total_sent += bytes;
    reply += bytes;
    len -= bytes;
  }
  printf("total file size sent : %ld\n", total_sent);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using EPOLLET makes your life harder and it's not needed unless you know why you need it. Do you really understand EPOLLET?

Comment: @user253751 Trying to understanding EPOLLET to get that performance edge. Yes, I have read manpages of epoll and all. Some things seem to be confusing but it's clearing out now. Thank you all

Comment: what is the performance edge you are trying to get with EPOLLET? Do you know it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is my approach correct?

As you discovered, your original approach (of looping on the `EAGAIN`) has the drawback that a single badly-behaving client can cause the thread to busy-loop and stop handling other clients, so it's not a great approach for servers that support multiple clients.

Your proposed new approach is better, because even if some clients are having network trouble, handling of the other clients can continue as usual.

> If I implement the above approach, I'd need to have one buffer per
> client, because I need to keep the "unsend" message which I couldn't
> due to send() returning -1. Isn't that memory inefficient?

It certainly *could* be memory-inefficient, but there are things you can do to reduce memory usage.

One thing you could do is reduce the size of the potentially-unsent message.  In your example, you mention generating 1MB worth of data for a client, and then having to buffer that up.  But is it really necessary to generate the entire megabyte of data up-front?  Why not just generate 1KB of data instead, and once that 1KB of data has been passed to `send()`, generate the next 1KB, and so on, until the entire 1MB has been sent that way?  If you are reading the data from a file, that should be pretty straightforward to implement, and that would reduce the potential worst-case memory usage of your example by a factor of 1000.  (If you're generating the data some other way, it might be a bit more complicated to implement this, but still doable)

Another potentially-applicable way to reduce memory usage would be to use reference-counting to share data.  e.g. if you know many clients are likely to request the same data at around the same time, then instead of loading a separate copy of the data into RAM for each client, you could load a single copy of the data, let all the clients read from it directly, and keep a reference-count to it and free the data when the reference-count drops to zero.  (If the data is on disk, you could go even further and `mmap()` the data so that it *looks* like it's in RAM, but actually the MMU is secretly demand-reading it directly out of the disk/disk-cache when its virtual addresses are being accessed by the program)

As for a "queue structure", that might work, but the main things you'd want to keep track of for each client are:

- For edge-triggering, whether the `EPOLLOUTET` bit is currently set for that client.
- Whether you have data you want to send to that client ASAP (either in RAM, or on disk, or even just potential data that you haven't generated yet but you know that the client wants).  This will determine whether or not the `EPOLLOUT` bit should be set for that client.
- Where in the overall outgoing data-stream you are (so that you know what bytes you already passed to `send()`, and therefore which bytes should be passed to `send()` then next time the socket indicates it is ready-for-write)
- Whatever state info you need to "generate some more bytes" on demand for the client's outgoing-data-stream.  (This could be the bytes themselves, but it doesn't have to be; just the info necessary to generate them when you do need them.  e.g. for the reading-from-file case, this might be just the `FILE *` pointer to the open file-handle)

Note that with the above info, you could still have a (hopefully small) per-client resend-buffer that holds the "leftover" bytes that you previously tried to pass in to `send()` but that `send()` refused to accept... or if you prefer to, you could skip the resend-buffer entirely and extend the "generate-bytes" functionality described above to be able to re-generate previously-generated bytes starting at a specified byte-offset from the top of the stream.  That could save a bit of per-client RAM, at the cost of adding some additional code-complexity.

Comment: A very nice answer! Sending 1KB of data for large files is certainly suitable, but doing so increases the amount of fread() and thus the amount of syscall I do to get content of the file, which will have a performance overhead iirc. Using mmap is certainly the better way. Next, the logic were I mark the event as EPOLLOUT when send returns -1 and then remove EPOLLOUT when I can send, is that correct? Or is it since edge-triggered, it won't matter since epoll will only notify me when I go from full buffer to "can send"?

Comment: I heard somewhere that I am supposed to mark the socket with EPOLLOUT when I get -1 from send and then remove it using epoll_ctl when I have sent everything. I am not sure how this works though.

Comment: @Cardinal note that `fread()` is not a system call... the C runtime provides `fread()` as a *buffered wrapper around* the `read()` system call, which means that each call to `fread()` is (on average) much cheaper than an actual `read()` system call would be (because the C runtime only calls the underlying `read()` call, in a larger amount, when it actually needs to refill its internal buffer -- many/most `fread()` calls can be satisfied with the equivalent of a `memcpy()`)

Comment: @Cardinal I haven't used the edge-triggered mode myself, but if it works the way the name indicates, I would expect you'd get a notification only when the socket goes from buffer-full to "can send" (or vice-versa).  I think you'd have to experiment to verify that (or ask someone more knowledgable than me :))

Comment: @Cardinal in general the presence of an `EPOLLOUT` mark means you are telling `epoll()` that you have data you want to send, so please notify you when there is buffer-space available for outgoing data.  `send()` returning `-1/EGAIN` usually indicates that you have outgoing data you want to send (i.e. the bytes that you tried to pass to `send()` but it refused to absorb), so that's a common case of the general logic.

Comment: Yeah, I tried out some experiment. EPOLLOUT with EPOLLET only tells you that the buffer has become empty, so we have use it. In case of level triggered, EPOLLOUT keeps on telling you that you can send out data (because the send buffer is ready).  As for many/most fread() calls can be satisfied with equivalent of a memcpy(), can you clarify? This is a bit confusing for me. 
Another question that I wanted to ask was that when I use `printft 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` | socat -t30 - TCP:localhost:8888, I get no response back which is most likely caused due to race condition

Comment: I checked using wireshark and saw that socat instantly sends a FIN packet after making a request, and correspondingly my server closes the fd, sending back a [FIN,ACK], and thus doesn't send any messages. Is it fine to send message to a socket that has been closed by peer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254048/discussion-between-jeremy-friesner-and-cardinal).